# Batch script to copy Data from subfolder

Tags: batch-file

I got a code that searches specific PDFs according to the `list.txt` and copies them from the `files1` folder to the `copyFiles` folder.

```
@echo off

FOR /f %%f IN (List.txt) DO xcopy "C:\Users\files1\%%f.pdf" "C:\Users\copyFiles" 

pause
```

now I don't only want to search in the `files1` folder but also e.g `files2` and `files3` folder.

Is there an easy way to search through a directory combined with my current code?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could just repeat that line of code and replace `files1` with `files2`. etc....etc...

Comment: I assume that will always give me an "data not found" in the cmd.exe and I accually need to see when the data really doesn't exist. Also there is a large number of folders I need to search through.

Comment: Your first question did not get any feedback or answer and this one seems to be headed in the same direction because your task seems very unclear to me. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Please learn, [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why using `xcopy` to copy files? Do you need to move FILES found or all folder structure?

Comment: What's wrong with adding a nested loop, `For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("List.txt") Do For %%B In ("files1" "files2" "files3") Do XCopy "C:\Users\%%~B\%%~A.pdf"...`?